# Windows 11 - C:\Windows is a file not a directory of size 0 B. DISM tool try repair and other methods

Tags: windows, windows-11, event-log, filesystem-corruption, dism

`C:\Windows` is a file of size 0 B.
What is happening in the system:

```
Explorer.exe
Location is not available.
C:\ not available.
Access denied.

WinAnotherOS:\Users\user01>C:
Access denied

WinAnotherOS:\WINDOWS\system32>C:
C:\>
C:\>cd Users
C:\Users>
C:\>cd Windows
The directory name is invalid.

The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
C:\>attrib +r C:\Windows
Unable to change attribute - C:\Windows

C:\>dir windows
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Directory of C:\
16.12.2022  13:54                 0 Windows
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
```

Have any ideas?
I got Windows 11 USB bootable and i can use Repair Your Computer. I tried like this:

```
X:\sources>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image Version: 10.0.22621.525

Error: 87

The cleanup-image option is unknown.
For more information, refer to the help by running DISM.exe /?.

The DISM log file can be found at X:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

After the first launch, such green squares resembling a QR code appeared on the screen, 7 rows and at the very top three or more blue lines horizontally. It's not really GSoD.
I have little knowledge of the Windows event log. But there's no way to check it?
Maybe there would be entries what exactly happened to this WINDOWS directory or what with the error.

**Edit:**

D: is Windows 11 installation USB, C: where is Windows directory which doesn't work. DISM try.

```
X:\sources>Dism /image:C: /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:ESD:D:\sources\install.esd:5 /LimitAccess

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1


Error: 267

Unable to access the image.
Make sure that the image path and the Windows directory for the image exist and you have Read permissions on the folder.

The DISM log file can be found at X:\windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

From Windows 11 installation USB from "Repair Your Computer" (cmd.exe)

I can read C:\Program Files\7-Zip\readme.txt and other files.

Comment: Your DISM command is syntactically incorrect outside of a working bootable installation of Windows. It appears you’re booting to WinRE. My suggestion reinstall Windows on the primary storage device.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, `Repair Your Computer` from Win 11 ISO. Can i use this command on WinRe: `Dism /image:C: /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:ESD:D:\sources\install.esd:5 /LimitAccess`? Here I also had a problem with the /image switch. I don't know what I filled in wrong that there was an error. Maybe it was DISM Error 1392 I don't remember. I'll check back later. Perhaps I can't make it through a corrupt `Widows` directory/file. Can it block the process?

Comment: You will be unable to run that command from within WinRE, again, the syntax isn’t correct. You won’t be able to run a command from WinRE that repairs your installation. In my experience of Windows cannot boot, and the only thing that works is WinRE, the installation is likely corrupt due to a storage device failure. Your Windows installation doesn’t reside on the C drive, since your booted into WinRE, you don’t have a mounted windows image on the d drive

Comment: "I got Windows 11 USB bootable." By that, do you mean you have an actual Windows 11 operating system running from USB (which I doubt), or that you **made a Windows 11 installation USB**? Those are two very different animals!

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - While the author clearly has some massive knowledge gaps, they are booting into WinRE, that exists on a bootable Windows installation media flash drive. This fact is based on the clear evidence contained in the question

Comment: @Ramhound, exactly, and he does not seem to understand there's little worth doing with that drive (other than slip-streaming software). Why run DISM at all? This is an X-Y problem -- don't waste resources answering a question that shows such misunderstanding.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - While theoretically it should be possible to point DISM to your Windows installation and provide it a source so the command can run, in my experience, it rarely works and the syntax the author is using isn’t correct. They are essentially trying to run DISM against WinRE not their Windows installation. The drive appears to have suffered massive data loss.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik **made a Windows 11 installation USB**

Comment: @nie_znaleziono, that is not able to *boot* from Windows 11, only to install it. Don't attempt to repair it; just make another installation USB using the media creation tool: https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11

Comment: @Ramhound why syntax isn't correct? Windows reside on the C drive, I checked with `dispart, list volume`, i have a mounted windows image on the d drive (Windows 11 installation USB, for example D:\sources\install.esd, unpacked files) I don't know if I understand correctly and how to do it. "the syntax the author is using isn’t correct" why? "the drive appears to have suffered massive data loss." no, i have access to all files under linux (Program Files for example). And Error: 267 I was wrong.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I just started the system from this (media creation tool ISO USB Rufus) i can also use cmd.exe directly from windows it still works (safe mode no longer) I still have minimal hope that I will be able to attach files to C:\Windows via DISM

Comment: this is really weird before on linux it acted as an empty directory now it's a file, when it was an empty directory, boot it would pop up a blue screen with options and you could run cmd.exe, now it only shows the uefi logo and nothing happens. Though I don't know if there is a difference (system cmd vs Windows 11 installation USB cmd)

Comment: the main post was edited if anyone didn't notice

Comment: if i delete `C:\Windows` will it unlock further process? I was hoping to get it back, so I feel a bit sorry for removing it. I remind you to see above what is happening with `attrib +r C:\Windows`

Comment: what does it mean "Unable to access the image."? see edit above

Comment: "Windows reside on the C drive," -To my knowledge you can't mount an ISO while within WinRE. You said your Windows installation directory, was 0 bytes, the only way that would be the case is if you had zero permissions to the disk (which shouldn't be the case and suggest a file system problem) or because data didn't exist in the folder which suggest the system drive suffered catastrophic failure.

Comment: "what does it mean "Unable to access the image."? " - It means the path to the mount Windows Image file (`install.esd`), and DISM is unable to find the image, and thus the path to the file is incorrect. It should actually be a install.wim never seen DISK work properly with a .esd file.

Comment: "D: is Windows 11 installation USB," - Actually X: is the installation media.  Your information in your question confirms that's the case.

Comment: I have burned ISO with Windows 11 to flash drive. On X: i don't see `install.wim`, but on D: i see it. I can use mkdir and other commands on the C: drive. same result on version win11 with `install.wim` Error: 267

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened to your computer.  Windows 11 does not convert the Windows folder to a file.

Windows is not running (cannot without its files) so Repair cannot work.

You will need to reinstall Windows 11. If you have a working recovery partition, try to use that.

If not, download the Windows 11 ISO to a bootable USB key and install from that.

Try booting the system with a bootable USB key to see if you can recover any files before you begin reinstalling

Comment: I did all these things. Do you not know? I said "I got Windows 11 USB bootable ISO". I have access to all files (for example Program Files, Users) except `Windows` directory. It's true in safe mode a black screen pops up. I prefer the harder way through DISM and event log (journal).

Comment: If you cannot start and get files then the file structure may be too messed up. Not sure. But you will have to reinstall Windows as I noted. No other way at this point.

Comment: There must be another solution. I have hope in DISM. Can't check the windows event log? Like I said before I saw green squares.

Comment: Sorry, no hope.   You must reinstall Windows. Other solutions require Windows to be running and it is not.

Comment: “Can't check the windows event log?” - No; WinRE doesn’t have the tools required to extract the event logs from your Windows installation. In fact there are no tools that exist that can allow you to view the event logs from your installation from outside of that particular Windows installation. If your Windows installation cannot boot then you need to reinstall Windows since nearly all failures that result in WinRE being the only thing that works in my considerable decades of experience is storage related issues